# Push scheduled notifications when app is not running

Tags: java, android

First of all: this question is very similar to my last one, but answer couldn't help me...

I am making a To-Do app. I got stuck on pushing notifications (even when app is not running).
My achieve is to push a notification about a to-do task, even if the app is not running.

e.g.
I make a new to-do task about homework on x/y/2021 at mm:hh. App must push a notification at that moment, even while app is not running

Scheduling (delay as 10 is just to debugging):

```
    OneTimeWorkRequest notificationWorker = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker.class)
            .setInitialDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setInputData(new Data.Builder().putString("title", "Note").build()).build();

    WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(this);
    workManager.enqueue(notificationWorker);
```

Class extending Worker:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    String date = getInputData().getString("date");
    String time = getInputData().getString("time");
    String title = getInputData().getString("title");
    String description = getInputData().getString("description");
    int delay = getInputData().getInt("delay", 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "note")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentInfo(date + " at " + time)
            .setContentText(description)
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

    return Result.success();
}
```

Comment: this *should* work but you need to be aware that WorkManager isn't very friendly with exact execution... it looks at some internal "battery health" stuff, and decides when to execute, so a 10second delay might end up being 15mins while the app is in background or not running. keep your phone on charger and give it an hour to see if your code will work alright at all, then fine tune/debug from there.

Comment: Thanks for your help! In fact when I read WorkManager documentation, I got something about that.  I have done as @SamiShorman said: tryng with another device. I tried with another, but same model as mine: Huawei Y6 2017. Its battery was 31% and pushed notification after 10 seconds even if the app wasn't running... My device at 81% not... Has someone any tips to fix it?

Comment: Huawei devices have that hiden menu which you can access by typing in some number... one additional thing to do is to set your app to be ignored by battery optimizations, as Huawei likes to kill of processes that arent in foreground. You can't fight these battles against vendor-specific changes. You won't win. just adapt your code to do stuff differently for different vendors.

Comment: I've already knew it. Ok, great... Could you help me about it? To set my app to be ignored by battery optimization

Comment: Different vendors have different explicit intents to take the user there, so at best you just display a dialog with a button that takes them to the "settings"/"battery optimization" screen where they have to manually disable battery optimizations for your app.

Comment: That's where I get stuck on! I cannot doing it! I tried a lot of... I enable my app on my phone to work also on semi-standby. Nothing to do!

Answer (score 1):

Honestly i dont read your code but take a look at workManager(because it's designed for these things) :

Android workManager documentation:

> WorkManager is an API that makes it easy to schedule deferrable, asynchronous tasks that are expected to run even if the app exits or the device restarts. The WorkManager API is a suitable and recommended replacement for all previous Android background scheduling APIs, including FirebaseJobDispatcher, GcmNetworkManager, and Job Scheduler. WorkManager incorporates the features of its predecessors in a modern, consistent API that works back to API level 14 while also being conscious of battery life.

workManager:https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

example(i think this is what u want):https://medium.com/@ifr0z/workmanager-notification-date-and-time-pickers-aad1d938b0a3

Comment: Already done! But didn't worked. It push notifications only when app was opened. Maybe I failed writing code. Could you link some example?

Comment: As I said, I have already tried this solution. It doesn't pushes notification when app is not running. Just done while app is running. I am gonna updating code

Comment: try your code on other phone because some rom's kill all background work, just to check if there is any errors in your code.

Comment: Done! And you were right. Now I am looking for a tip about it... Could you see my comment at @Shark?